# how go back to previous activity not to a fragment of previous activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am in (Fragment 1) of Activity B, I reached here from Fragment 1 Activity A. when I Click of back button I am going back to back to  Fragment 1 Activity A, But instead, I want to go back directly Activity A and not to any Fragment of Activty A ?

How to do this?

Comment: You can start ActivityA with a new intent with the flag NEW_TASK, NO_HISTORY (or some combination) that will start a new ActivityA instead of using the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Fragment 1 Activity A, start your activity B through getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent, myRequestCode)

In your Activity B, override onBackPressed, and finish Activity B.

In Activity A, in onActivityResult, check if the request code matches the one you passed in earlier, and if it does, use the fragment manager to remove the fragment (1) that you earlier added to Activity A

Answer (score 0):

While going to Fragment 1 of Activity B from Fragment 1 Activity A before committing the transaction do:

In Fragment 1 Activity A do:

```
Frag1ActB dashboard = new Frag1ActB();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);//catch here
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, dashboard, "tag").commitAllowingStateLoss();
```